# Postgresql Database Connectivity

Tags: postgresql

How secure is connecting Postgres Database using phpPgAdmin through port 80?

What is the difference between accessing postgres DB through database client tools through port 5432 and acccessing it  using phpPgAdmin through port 80?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Different; I wouldn't necessarily say more or less secure so long as you've patched [the major security hole announced for PostgreSQL yesterday](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1456/).

If you connect direct to a PostgreSQL that wasn't patched for then your exposure is [denial of service including data destruction for any connection before authentication has taken place](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-1899). If you connect to a patched PostgreSQL then you're fine; PostgreSQL has a pretty solid security history and this vulnerability is the first serious one seen in seven years.

If you use PHPPgAdmin as a front-end then you're relying on the security of your web server authentication to control access to PostgreSQL and you're relying on secure coding in PHPPgAdmin  to avoid authentication bypass attacks etc.

Either way you need to keep on top of security patches. Using phpPgAdmin gives you a bigger attack surface so I'd tend to view direct PostgreSQL connection as the more secure option, particularly if you set the server to require SSL for remote connections and limit the allowed IP range with the firewall.

The best option is still "neither of the above":

- Have PostgreSQL listening only on localhost and trusted internal network interfaces or firewall it off;
- ssh in to the server and use `psql`.